# is it possible to recover my exodus wallet, from a backup file?

Tags: private-key, hardware-wallet, passphrase, ledger-hardware-wallet, exodus

I have a one year old back-up (exodus.zip). When extracted from ZIP and placed that folder in AppData/Roaming/ now it asks for passwords which I don't remember anymore.

Inside the 'exodus.wallet' folder there are 6 files, five (info, seed, storage, twofactor, twofactor-secret) of them are '.seco' extension **and** one is 'passphrase.json'.

'passphrase.json' is as follows:

```
{
  "passphrase": "44character longs tring",
  "system": true
}
```

Is all my money gone? Or is there any way to recover?